# Installing RAILS on MAC OS 10.9 Mavericks (beta)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos

I'm running OS X Mavericks 10.9 beta and now is a good time to get back to learning Ruby on Rails. Happy to know that 10.9 includes Ruby 2.0

But I'm having trouble installing Rails.

using the command - sudo gem install rails

results in this..

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/atomic-1.1.10 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/atomic-1.1.10/ext/gem_make.out

Any advice?

Thanks

Shannon

Comment: You may `brew install ruby-build` if you use Homebrew.

Comment: Do you have Xcode and the command line tools installed?

Comment: 10.9 changed the place for command line tools, it now in /Developer and managed by the system, when installing rails, it's still searching for command line tool in the Xcode. So, you can get a Xcode4, switch to it and install... no problem at all.

Answer (score 2):

For me this problem was fixed by running the following command:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [post](http://blog.wyeworks.com/2012/4/13/my-osx-rails-installation-using-homebrew-and-rbenv-step-by-step/)

It's not recommended to use your system Ruby, you can use it in a sandbox like RVM or rbenv.

Comment: Hi, You must use gems with careful and they'll install in your PATH's Ruby. It's easier to fix something in a Ruby that's installed in a sandbox (your users path) than some Ruby installed with root permissions in your system.

Comment: I see what you mean, but whats the point for apple to bundle ruby with OSX?

Comment: To run Ruby scripts too, but as a dev, is advise you to install Ruby using Rbenv or rvm.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 5 is required.

and ..

```
$ xcode-select -p
/Applications/Xcode5-DP3.app/Contents/Developer
```

it's work .

or

see [Install Ruby 2.0 on Mac OS X without RVM](http://blog.lsong.org/2013/08/install-ruby-2-0-on-mac-os-x-without-rvm/)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using Xcode 5.0.1 GM seed, not the Xcode downloaded from the App Store.  That fixed a similar problem for me.